# how to link table output (also available by url in json format) and google maps by clicking a button?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I have a situation in which I have dynamic table/grid output which is also represented by a dynamic url with google maps valid json output (eg for markers). Everything works fine on it's own e.g. with the input of a static json file.

I would like an option to update the map (eg the markers) by clicking on a button when I've new table/grid/json-by-url output. An automatic map update without clicking is also an option.

I am using a Jquery/Json-input/Google Maps combination, so far.

Please could someone give me some guidance-direction or an article about how to?

best regards
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I believe `jquery-ui-map` may be of use to you:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code

It seems to allow dynamically adding markers.

Example with add/remove:

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geocoding.html